# If statements in shaders - implications and consequences

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl, hlsl, directx

I've heard a lot that in shader development, you absolutely need to avoid branching and so if statements.

But why? Does this have a real impact on performances on old and modern hardware or is it more a case by case choice depending on your scenario?

When possible, it's better to use preprocessor macros but when it's not, what can we do?

What is the purpose of using `flatten` or `branch` attributes? Are there other solutions available?

Comment: dupe of one of the following: http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/2508/137 http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/259/137 http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/280/137