# How do modern GPUs handle branching instructions in shader code?

Tags: shader, gpu

It has often been recommended to avoid branching conditions in shaders.

Why? What happens exactly in modern GPUs in that case? 
Is it still recommended to avoid branching?

Comment: duplicate of https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/259/137 and https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/280/137

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a constant condition more costly than switching shaders?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/280/is-a-constant-condition-more-costly-than-switching-shaders)